# Meteor session with big data

Tags: angularjs, session, meteor

In my Meteor app I get array of object from `HTTP POST`and I would like to use data in another page I use `Session set` and `Session get` with out any problem expet Session will distroy upon page refresh there for I use some package like:`smeevil:session-store` & `amplify` to persist session and couple more but regarding data is big I get `qouta exceed` error is there anyway elese to prevent Session destroy of refresh or `time out`for session?

all problem is from client side and browser console .there is nothing in server side

```
search_id:"3mlejmn7chmvvfweabjopfrsvm"
$$hashKey:"object:442"
address:"1216/1 Charoean Krung Road Bangkok 10500   Charoean Krung Road"
category:2.5
city_code:"C!000864"
country:"TH"
fullRate:7.19
geolocation:
latitude:13.725711
longitude:100.515984
__proto__:
Object
hotel_code:"H!0262688"
images:
main_image:"hotels/images/1a/a9/1aa9da341f7c3560f2d1f73e9bcbf67a7a45918c.jpg"
__proto__:
Object
name:"New Road Guest House"
rates:Array(14)[another arrays]
```

this is sample of data that return from `http` and each time its between 100 to 650 set of these information and if user want to change each parameter of search it will update and again new set of data will return and its not just 1 source for data but 3-4 source 
mean while I try to define `minimongo` client side collection but it will be flash and empty after each browser refresh as well

PS: I use angular inside Meteor
Thanks for any idea

Comment: Meteor.Session is not made to store data that would persist. You should use Collections to store and display data over time.

Comment: @Victor Thanks for answer but I dont think Collections are working because this HTTP post will update and change by every 2-3 minutes and have code that expire in 30 min

Comment: Can you provide example of what you are trying to do ? - one update every 2/3 minutes doesn't seem to be a big challenge for collections...

Comment: How "big" is the big data? And which part of your environment tells you `quota exceeded`? The browser console? Server console?

Comment: @Jankapunkt  I edit my question